# How to resize the Frame widget on tkinter ? -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want the Frame widget to take all the window of tkinter but it seems to have no effect plus when I try to move the label (who is inside the frame) it mysteriously disapear Althought the Frame is supposed to have the same size as root.

I specified the height and width for root because I don't know how to make the global window of the project just defined by the height and width of the Frame widget.(so I used geometry to assign a height and width to root)

I've heard about "frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)" but I can't use pack because I use grid for the widgets that are inside the Frame ( and I want to keep grid) so I used .place on Frame instead but I don't know how to do the same thing with place() as we did with pack.

If the frame can resize correctly that I suppose the widget Label will not disapear when we drag it (because the space will be bigger)

```
   import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
frame = Frame(root,width=800,height=600)
frame.place(x=0,y=0)


label = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL',fg='green')
label.grid(column=0,row=0)


label2 = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL2',fg='green')
label3 = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL3',fg='green')

def change(event):
    
    label['text'] = '˅LABEL'
    label2.grid(column=0,row=1)
    label3.grid(column=0,row=2)
    if label['text'] == '˅LABEL':
        label.bind('<Button-1>', hide)

def hide(event):
    label['text'] = '˃LABEL'
    label2.grid_forget()
    label3.grid_forget()
    if label['text'] == '˃LABEL':
        label.bind('<Button-1>',change)
        
label.bind('<Button-1>',change)

def make_draggable(widget):
    widget.bind("<Button-1>", on_drag_start)
    widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)

def on_drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y

def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)

make_draggable(label)


root.mainloop()
```

You can try it if you want

FIRST EDIT : "By default, Tkinter Frame fits to its children and thus its width and height depends on its children. You can override this behavior and force a specific width and height to the frame. To force the width and height of frame widget call pack_propagate(0) on the frame."

I can't do it with place() ? (Like I said I can't use pack() for what I want to do)

Comment: `.place()` does not adjust the parent size.

Comment: But I want to use grid for the child. The problem is : grid inside pack is not ok, it doesn't work. But It work with place()

Comment: I also want to use place for saying later to center the widgets on x and specify a y for them

Comment: @MrTiredVeryTired: _"The problem is : grid inside pack is not ok, it doesn't work."_ is not true. You can use grid inside a widget that was added with pack to some other widget.

Comment: But why I can't resize the Frame ? Or when I define a size for the frame with width and height it doesn't work. And when I drag my label it disapear (it's a frame problem ?)

Comment: If I set label = Label(root....) instad of frame it will display : "_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack" That's why I said I can't use pack() before grid() or a thing like that

Comment: Have you ever tried `frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)`? It works!

Comment: I think It works with frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1) but it didn't work before, it's weird